# Split String array to find and check checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a string split by commas. I use the javascript command split to break it into an array.

I have a group of checkboxes called ciContact.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
    <tr>
        <td><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ciContact[]" value="Call" id="ciContact_0" />
      Call</label></td>
    <td><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ciContact[]" value="Email" id="ciContact_1" />
      Email</label></td>

        <td><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="ciContact[]" value="Text" id="ciContact_2" />
      Text</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The array contains just the values that need to be checked. These values are echoed back from an AJAX call that is JSON-encoded. However, these values (ciContact) are all stored in the MySQL database as a comma-delimited array. There is a reason I did it that way. So how do I read the values of my comma-delimited array and check the appropriate checkboxes?

I've tried:

```
var ciContact = data.split(", ");
for (var j = 0; j < ciContact.length; j++)
    {
var selected = $('name=ciContact').find('value='+ ciContact[i]);
selected.attr("checked","checked");
}
```

I'm way off on that one. Ha!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ciContact = data.split(", ");
for (var j = 0; j < ciContact.length; j++) {
    $('input[name^=ciContact][value=' + ciContact[j] + ']').attr('checked','checked');`
}
```

Or, for slightly better performance:

```
var ciContact = data.split(", "),
    $inputs = $('input[name^=ciContact]');
for (var j = 0; j < ciContact.length; j++) {
    $inputs.filter('[value=' + ciContact[j] + ']').attr('checked','checked');`
}
```

Or, fancy:

```
var ciContact = data.split(", ").join('], [value='),
    $inputs = $('input[name^=ciContact]');

$inputs.filter('[value=' + ciContact + ']').attr('checked','checked');
```

Comment: If you're using a new version of jQuery (1.6+), .prop("checked", true) is a better alternative to .attr("checked", "checked")

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong. Your selector is not correct and you are using the wrong loop variable (`i` instead of `j`).

This should do it:

```
var ciContact = data.split(", "),
    $elements = $('input[name="ciContact[]"]');

for (var j = 0; j < ciContact.length; j++) {
    $elements.filter('[value="' + ciContact[j] + '"]').attr("checked","checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ciContact = data.split(", ");
var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox[name="ciContact[]"]');

for (var j = 0; j < ciContact.length; j++){
    checkboxes
        .filter('[value="'+ciContact[j]+'"]')
        .attr("checked","checked");
}
```

You can [see it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/td6KL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ciContact = data.split(", ");
var tmpHash = {};
for(var i = 0; i < ciContact.length; i++){
    tmpHash[$.trim(ciContact[i])] = 1; // if you are pretty sure that your data is clean, skip $.trim()
}

$('input[name="ciContact[]"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() in tmpHash){
        $(this).attr('checked', 'true');
    }
}
```

or there is a new javascript lib called tog, you can utilise it for your ajax handling.

```
function checkBox(data, all_options){
    var ciContact = data.split(", ");
    var tmpHash = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < ciContact.length; i++){
        tmpHash[$.trim(ciContact[i])] = 1; // if you are pretty sure that your data is clean, skip $.trim()
    }

    return Tog().map(all_options, function(opt, key, _num){
        var t = tog.Td().Tog('label').checkbox('$ciContact[]')
            .id('ciContact_', _num);
        if(opt in tmpHash){ t.checked() }

        // close the check box, and append the value as its label
        t.close().cont(opt);
        return t;
    }).html();
}
```

Calling checkBox(data, options) will give you the piece of html.
and you can append it to something like $('table tr')
At your backend, you would simply need to dump all your options into a json string.
And your client side can easily get it as this so-called 'all_options'